# Buffer each line locally on a serial terminal

Tags: tty, kermit

I use kermit to connect to a device over serial.  The device is quite "dumb" and doesn't have any fancy shell.  It is really just receiving commands over serial and sending outputs back over serial.

The problem is I make a type every other word, and I have no way to backspace, so I simply have to start over again.

Is there some way I can get kermit (or equivalent) to buffer each line locally for editing before sending it down the line when I press enter, so that I can backspace if I need to?

Comment: Which version of kermit do you have installed?

Comment: Kermit 9.0.302.

Answer (score 1):

To suggest an alternative, have you tried `minicom` or `screen`. The thing you are wanting is to change the line disciplne, it sounds like you are in raw mode (each character sent to remote) instead of buffered (or cooked) mode (cr triggers buffer to be sent). there is also a half way house semi-cooked mode (cbreak).

All these values can be set using the `stty` command, however it is possible that `kermit` will override them when it initialises, unless you cater for that.

Then you want ^? (DEL) to be the delete character. There is a section about this in the Kermit documentation. [here](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ckubwr.html#x3.3.3). Which explains how to set rudimentary terminal profile for `xterm`.

So I would suggest using `minicom`, but this might be impossible due to the remote device's transfer protocol. If you have further information then [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/120711/edit) your original question, unless it really is a comment.

Note when you use stty it is the input you set to the serial device not the output `stty [options] </dev/sttyN` (since it wants to display output on your screen).

Comment: Is it possible to use `screen` in the buffered (cooked) lines mode like this? I can't find anything in the man file or google...

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying for two or three hours to figure out how to do this with `screen` or `minicom`, and I can't figure it out. I'm not saying that there isn't a way to do get those programs to buffer lines and such but... if there is, I don't know it.

I am now using a program called [CoolTerm by Roger Meier](http://freeware.the-meiers.org). It's freeware, works on Linux/Windows/OS X with a nice looking GUI, and it's dead simple to make the line buffering work. Just click on Options and select the Terminal view from the list to the left, and change the Terminal Mode to Line Mode (default is still Raw Mode).

[This guide by Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/coolterm-windows-mac-linux) is helpful.